# Eliminating Consecutive Numbers

Tags: python

If you have a range of numbers from 1-49 with 6 numbers to choose from, there are nearly 14 million combinations. Using my current script, I currently have only 7.2 million combinations remaining. Of the 7.2 million remaining combinations, I want to eliminate all 3, 4, 5, 6, dual, and triple consecutive numbers. 
Example:

- 3 consecutive: 1, 2, 3, x, x, x
- 4 consecutive: 3, 4, 5, 6, x, x
- 5 consecutive: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, x
- 6 consecutive: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- double separate consecutive: 1, 2, 5, 6, 14, 18
- triple separate consecutive: 1, 2, 9, 10, 22, 23

Note: combinations such as 1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15 must also be eliminated or else they conflict with the rule that double and triple consecutive combinations to be eliminated.

I'm looking to find how many combinations of the 7.2 million remaining combinations have zero consecutive numbers (all mixed) and only 1 consecutive pair.

Thank you!

```py
import functools

_MIN_SUM     = 120
_MAX_SUM     = 180
_MIN_NUM     = 1
_MAX_NUM     = 49
_NUM_CHOICES = 6
_MIN_ODDS    = 2
_MAX_ODDS    = 4

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n, l, s = 0, odds = 0):
    if s > _MAX_SUM or odds > _MAX_ODDS:
        return 0
    if n == 0 :
        return int(s >= _MIN_SUM and odds >= _MIN_ODDS)
    return sum(f(n-1, i+1, s+i, odds + i % 2) for i in range(l, _MAX_NUM+1))


result = f(_NUM_CHOICES, _MIN_NUM)

print('Number of choices = {}'.format(result))
```

Comment: I think this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). It sounds like you just want to get all combinations that only have exactly one consecutive pair, so why not rephrase the question to ask about the outcome you want? If you clarify that, we may be able to help more efficiently.

Comment: Instead of looking for the 6 mentioned combinations, just check for combinations that have zero consecutive numbers (all mixed) or only 1 consecutive pair.

Comment: I need all combinations that only have exactly one consecutive pair and also zero consecutive numbers in a selections of 6. All other combinations would be eliminated as a result.

Comment: So to clarify, you need the number of arrays of length 6 containing only values of 1-49 that only contain at most 1 pair of consecutive numbers?

Comment: @DaichiJameson - that's correct

Comment: Is it an array of 6 values or a set of 6 values? In all of you examples the numbers are unique in the group of 6, and they always seem to be increasing

Comment: @DaichiJameson - A set of 6 values. Only combinations, no permutations.

Comment: I agree with @Engineero that it'd be good to reword your question to specifically state that you want the number of combinations with at most a single pair of consecutive numbers, and it also might be good to post the question to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) since it's a combinatorics question

Answer (score 0):

While my answer should work, I think someone might be able to offer a faster solution.

Consider the following code:

```
not_allowed = []
for x in range(48):
    not_allowed.append([x, x+1, x+2])

# not_allowed = [ [0,1,2], [1,2,3], ... [11,12,13], ... [47,48,49] ]
my_numbers = [[1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 33], [1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 31], [12, 13, 14, 15, 23, 43]]
for x in my_numbers:
    for y in not_allowed:
        if set(y) <= set(x): # if [1,2,3] is a subset of [1,2,5,9,11,33], etc.
            # drop x
```

This code will remove all instances that contain double consecutive numbers, which is all you really need to check for, because triple, quadruple, etc. all imply double consecutive. Try implementing this and let me know how it works.

Comment: one consecutive pair is allowed so `[1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 33`]` is perfectly fine

Comment: Got it, I misread your question. All this requires is a simple fix in the code, which I can update now.

Comment: Sorry to correct you again but your update isn't correct either. Now `[1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 33]` will be accepted

Comment: You’re right, no worries on correcting me. Let me think about this and see if I can revise this more after work and give a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Also be mindful about the complexity of your algorithm. Try to minimise the amount of iterations necessary

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is probably to generate and filter. I used numpy to try to vectorize as much of this as I could:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
combos = np.array(list(combinations(range(1, 50), 6)))  # build all combos
# combos is shape (13983816, 6)
filt = np.where(np.bincount(np.where(np.abs(
    np.subtract(combos[:, :-1], combos[:, 1:])) == 1)[0]) <= 1)[0]  # magic!
filtered = combos[filt]
# filtered is shape (12489092, 6)
```

Breaking down that "magic" line

- First we subtract the first five items in the list from the last five items to get the differences between them. We do this for the entire set of combinations in one shot with `np.subtract(combos[:, :-1], combos[:, 1:])`. Note that `itertools.combinations` produces *sorted* combinations, on which this depends.
- Next we take the absolute value of these differences to make sure we only look at positive distances between numbers with `np.abs(...)`.
- Next we grab the indicies from this operation for the *entire* dataset that indicate a difference of `1` (consecutive numbers) with `np.where(... == 1)[0]`. Note that `np.where` returns a tuple where the first item are all of the rows, and the second item are all of the corresponding columns for our condition. This is important because any row value that shows up more than once tells us that we have more than one consecutive number in that row!
- So we count how many times each row shows up in our results with `np.bincount(...)`, which will return something like `[5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` indicating how many consecutive pairs are in each row of our combinations dataset.
- Finally we grab only the row numbers where there are 0 or 1 consecutive values with `np.where(... <= 1)[0]`.

I am returning *way* more combinations than you seem to indicate, but I feel fairly confident that this is working. By all means, poke holes in it in the comments and I will see if I can find fixes!

Bonus, because it's all vectorized, it's super fast!